# Mahapps.metro nuggets invalid markup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

So im using mahapps.metro to style my c# wpf application. Its working fine when Im working with my laptop, then i transfer my project to my colleague's laptop then it say's invalid markup. All the codes of mahapps.metro didnt recognized. We already installed the nuggets, build rebuild clean, but it didnt work. please help me Thanks![image: mahapps' xaml code invalid markup]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and full uninstall of MahApps and MahApps Resources from Nuget Manager resolved it.